# Composition of function and its inverse to get a log-concave function

Tags: random-variables, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If f is defined as $f(t,p) = g^{-1}(E(g(t,p))$ for any random variable $p$ and natural number $t$, what properties does $g$ have to have to make $f$ log-concave in t?